# How to prevent rdiff-backup from deleting files?

Tags: backup, data-recovery, rdiff-backup

I am using rdiff-backup to back up my data (on Ubuntu 20.04), which works quite smoothly - and I appreciate the incremental backup, keeping the data easily accessible.

However, since my internal hard drive is quite small, I would sometimes like to remove things after I have backed them up to the external backup drive. But that makes rdiff-backup remove it from the backup drive next time it is synced. Is there some way to prevent rdiff-backup from deleting previously backed up files that no longer exist on the source drive?

Answer (score 1):

If you delete a file then `rdiff-backup` does not delete the file from the backups.  The deleted file won't appear in the `Current mirror` after the next backup is run, but it is still available to restore.

Here is a basic example.

- create a directory with the files `A.txt` and `B.txt` to be backed up.

```
root@ubuntu:~# mkdir orig
root@ubuntu:~# uuidgen > orig/A.txt
root@ubuntu:~# uuidgen > orig/B.txt
```

- backup the directory with `rdiff-backup`

```
root@ubuntu:~# mkdir backup
root@ubuntu:~# rdiff-backup orig/ backup/
```

- delete the file `A.txt` from the original directory and perform a backup.

```
root@ubuntu:~# rm orig/A.txt
root@ubuntu:~# rdiff-backup orig/ backup/
```

- the file `A.txt` is no longer in the `backup` directory, but that only represents the `Current mirror`.

```
root@ubuntu:~# ls backup/
B.txt  rdiff-backup-data
root@ubuntu:~# rdiff-backup -l backup/
Found 1 increments:
    increments.2021-11-03T21:51:38Z.dir   Wed Nov  3 21:51:38 2021
Current mirror: Wed Nov  3 21:52:08 2021
```

- restore the directory from the previous increment `2021-11-03T21:51:38Z` and the file `A.txt` will be restored.

```
root@ubuntu:~# mkdir restore
root@ubuntu:~# rdiff-backup -r 2021-11-03T21:51:38Z backup/ restore/
root@ubuntu:~# ls restore/
A.txt  B.txt
```

- you can also do things like list the files available in a specific increment

```
root@ubuntu:~# rdiff-backup --list-at-time 2021-11-03T21:51:38Z backup/
.
A.txt
B.txt
```

**Links**

- https://rdiff-backup.net/docs/examples.html
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/rdiff-backup.1.html

Comment: I need the same OP needs - as far as I can tell, rdiff-backup also can rotate the snapshots, which means at a certain point, the deleted file will truely be gone. One would have wished, given that deletion is a default, to have a `--no-delete` argument (in which case we'd have just copying), but apparently, there no such option... (and for some reason, I cannot make an exclude filter, that will ignore wanting to delete files)

Comment: @sdbbs the backups are kept until you run `rdiff-backup --remove-older`.  If you delete the original file *and* you delete all the backups that contain the original file; then the original file will be gone.  I'm not sure how else you would want it to work.  Maybe you can create a new question giving an example of your issue.